# Mean (likelihood) encoding

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have a dataset called "data" with categorical values I'd like to encode with mean (likelihood/target) encoding rather than label encoding.

My dataset looks like:

```
data.head()

ID  X0  X1  X10 X100    X101    X102    X103    X104    X105    ... X90 X91 X92 X93 X94 X95 X96 X97 X98 X99
0   0   k   v   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   6   k   t   0   1   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
2   7   az  w   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
3   9   az  t   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
4   13  az  v   0   0   1   0   0   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   1   0
5 rows × 377 columns
```

I've tried:

```
# Select categorical features
cat_features = data.dtypes == 'object'

# Define function
def mean_encoding(df, cols, target):

    for c in cols:
        means = df.groupby(c)[target].mean()
        df[c].map(means)

    return df

# Encode
data = mean_encoding(data, cat_features, target)
```

which raises:

> KeyError: False

I've also tried:

```
# Define function
def mean_encoding(df, target):

    for c in df.columns:
        if df[c].dtype == 'object':
            means = df.groupby(c)[target].mean()
            df[c].map(means)

    return df
```

which raises:

> KeyError: 'Columns not found: 87.68, 87.43, 94.38, 72.11, 73.7, 74.0,
>   74.28, 76.26,...

I've concated train and test dataset into one called "data" and saved train target before dropping in the dataset as:

```
target = train.y
split = len(train)

data = pd.concat(objs=[train, test])
data = data.drop('y', axis=1)
data.shape
```

Help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not selecting categorical columns correctly. By doing`cat_features = data.dtypes == 'object'` you are not getting columns names,  instead you get boolean showing if column type is categorical or not. Resulting in KeyError: False

You can select categorical column as

```
mycolumns = data.columns
numerical_columns = data._get_numeric_data().columns
cat_features= list(set(mycolumns) - set(numerical_columns))
```

or

```
cat_features = df.select_dtypes(['object']).columns
```

Rest of you code will be same

```
  # Define function
  def mean_encoding(df, cols, target):

     for c in cols:
        means = df.groupby(c)[target].mean()
        df[c].map(means)

    return df

# Encode
data = mean_encoding(data, cat_features, target)
```

Comment: Yeah, I though so and it selects objects types well now. However when I fix it, it returns the same error as it the second part of the question. I think the another problem is with target values that are not a part of the dataset and are stored separatly.

Comment: I think you need to modify question and include ode definingwhat `target` values are or post other question. Also, it is not clear that at what line do you get the second error(columns not found)